# Magento Reinstallation

Tags: magento-1.8

My friend has been using Magento.  Now somehow some files from the hosting was deleted by him by mistake. Now if I go for a re installation, and use the existing data base will my old data be erased? I have seen that several files folders are missing.. What can be the possible solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using just default **Magento** with out any of the extensions, then it is not necessary to worry about the data.

If your **Magento** contains any of the custom developed extensions, then you will be loosing that functionality. But if are sure you can re-install those extensions which you had lost by accidentally; then your functionality will be back. But be aware on installing those extensions because as you are new I hope that you are not aware of the location of the files that are going to be placed with extension.

In magento folders, it will just save the images to the media folder and all the remaining data will be saved to database. Till you dont touch the database, then there are no worries about the data.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario where you have a live installation I would look at what you have or can get before you start.

If you have full backups from within Magento  = system | media | database. Then you are in a strong position to totally re-install Magento.

I would also go to phpmyadmin and backup the database directly from there too.

FTP your Media folder as pictures etc will link to the database.

Save all the data on your hard drive. Not on the server.

- So let us presume you have database backups from phpmyadmin and Magento system | media | database.

---

Option 1

Well even though you have backups I wouldn't go for a re-install - I would leave this to the last resort.

I would have a Magento clone. And test the data you have saved to see if it will work on a re-installation. Having done a few rebuilds from data it's not straightforward to go within Magento and click to revert to backups. In reality, the system backup doesn't and has never worked for me. reinstalling the Database is better done within phpmyadmin. And the Media folder is better done with FTP.

OK let's assume you now have a clone installation of Magento and have managed to load and successfully run the installation.

I would then be looking at one screen your Magento installation and the ftp to your friends' installation. to see what files are missing. Then simply transfer the files across.

---

Option 2

Again have a clone and look at the CORE files to skip through to see whats missing. Generally the CORE files don't change so they can be moved across.

If you have no installations of any plugins or themes then this makes your job easier because its a basic clone of installation files.

---

Option 3

### Expand the Magento files and do a best guess whats missing by looking at whats on the server and whats on the files. Just manually see if there's missing files. I would have thought that the missing files are low down in the begging of the tree rather than tucked away.

Hope this has been of some help drop me a line if you get stuck.
Jonathan
boom@boomdata.co.uk

Answer (score 0):

we have faced same scenario with our client, then we did below steps to outcome with this problem. It takes around 2 days and no risk factor.

1. Copy your existing server files in your system
2. Placed default magento with same version
3. Installed file comparison tools (winmerge,meld, etc.)
4. Disabled custom extensions for local and community codePools.
5. Compare core files from tools and copy from default version to your existing setup those are missing.
6. After copying your missing files, run the installation on your existing setup
7. Enable to your local and community pools extensions.
   Enjoy with your existing setup..